# Copy paste not working on ubuntu putty

Tags: putty, 13.10

I have been using putty to connect to one of my client server,here the problem is that copy and paste doesn't work. When I was on windows it used to work and now I want the same thing on ubuntu 13.10.

Comment: you might try adding a SHIFT to your commands, so CTRL+SHIFT+C/V. That is how how copy pasting is done in the terminal. (I also don't see how you would need Putty in Ubuntu; you can simply ssh using a terminal)

Comment: @GerhardBurger Haven't done it with the terminal.May be I need to check it out.

Comment: @GerhardBurger   BTW do you have any document I can refer to to do a SSH connection through the trnminal.

Comment: it is very simple, if you want to connect to test.server.com you simply type `ssh test.server.com` in the terminal. The more advanced options are described in the man pages: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/ssh.1.html

Comment: @GerhardBurger Ah thanks a lot got it and sorry for the nobish question I'm bit new to ubuntu.

Comment: no problem at all! Putty is a great program on windows ;) Did you in the end get the copy pasting working? You might also try the middle mouse button or enter, sometimes those can do a paste.

Comment: @GerhardBurger Yeah its working now.

Comment: FYI: ssh will not always allow you to access your serve.
I can only access the server via a putty window in Ubuntu.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssh/+bug/1254085

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You might try adding a <kbd>Shift</kbd> to your commands, so <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> / <kbd>V</kbd>. That is how copy pasting is done in the terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is used to abort terminal commands). Alternatively you can try pasting by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> or the middle mouse button.

In Ubuntu, you may wish to consider not using PuTTY at all: you can simply `ssh` using a terminal. For example, if you want to connect to `test.server.com`, you could simply type:

```
ssh test.server.com
```

If your username is different on the remote system, you can specify it by using this syntax:

```
ssh remote_username@remote_host
```

More advanced options are described in the [man pages](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/ssh.1.html).

Answer (score 18):

I found that selecting (left click and drag) would copy, and middle mouse (tap down on scroll wheel) would paste.  It worked for me, when adding the shift did not.

Comment: I am on ubuntu 15.10. Antonius' suggestion worked for me as well.

Comment: I am on ubuntu 18.04. Antonius' suggestion worked for me as well.

Answer (score 16):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> for paste, worked for Ubuntu 12.04 and putty

Answer (score 8):

Hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and press "Right click" and enjoy it!

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this. Works great on Mint based on Ubuntu

Answer (score 4):

With the mouse left-click, hold, and drag cursor to select+copy text to clipboard. Paste with center mouse wheel/button.

Answer (score 4):

You can configure the copy/paste behavior on Window → Selection as below.

[image: Putty Dialog]

Answer (score 1):

I used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and right click and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

On my Ubuntu 16 laptop, without a wheel mouse, I ran into lots of difficulties attempting to paste text into Putty, until I tried:

1. copying the text in another application;
2. leaving the text selected;
3. shifting to the Putty window;
4. clicking <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Choose 1 of the following for yourself:

A) Press/click on scroll bar to paste.

B) **Ctrl + Right Click** to get list of options to perform. (One of them would be paste from clipboard).

C) Directly login from your OS's terminal without using putty by using below command:

```
ssh user_name@host_name
```

For e.g.: Andrew@120.120.30.43
Then enter your password here.

Here you can use ***ctrl+shift+c*** for copy and ***ctrl+shift+v*** as we do in ubuntu's terminal

Note: above action can be done in putty too. by going to **selection** section.